# How to create a mirrored zpool after adding a drive to zpool?

Tags: zfs

I had a zpool with just one drive, with some content in it. I was willing to add a second drive as a mirror one but instead of "attach" command I used "add".

I still didn't use the pool after adding the second drive, but trying to removing it return:

```
$ sudo zpool remove bck2016 sdc1
cannot remove sdc1: only inactive hot spares, cache, top-level, or log devices can be removed.
```

Trying to force attach result in:

```
$ sudo zpool attach -f bck2016 sdb1 sdc1
invalid vdev specification
the following errors must be manually repaired:
/dev/sdc1 is part of active pool 'bck2016'
```

The current status is:

```
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: bck2016
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    bck2016     ONLINE       0     0     0
      sdb1      ONLINE       0     0     0
      sdc1      ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

How can I transform this pool to a mirrored one?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to remove a vdev added to a pool that way. Only spare or redundant vdevs can be detached, and even while you didn't write any new files to it, your pool is now configured as a concatenation of sdb1 and sdc1 so sdc1 is not considered redundant.

The only workaround is to backup everything elsewhere, destroy and rebuild your pool as a mirrored one, and restore from backup.

Comment: I would have expected someone with 15k rep would have recognised that this is extremely off topic for SO -- or am I wrong about that? Or is just that zfs belongs to Oracle now and you're working for Oracle too, so...

Comment: @EngineerDollery You are right. It is definitely off topic for SO but I didn't pay attention that was asked on SO. Asking for the question to be moved too.